# Is there a way to hide PHP warnings without access to php.ini?

Tags: wordpress

I don't have access to my client's production server's php.ini and I need to hide PHP warning errors. Is it possible and if so how?

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/5-new-features-php-7

Answer (score 1):

You may use .htaccess to hide errors, try these lines:

```
# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
```

[Source](https://perishablepress.com/how-to-enable-php-error-logging-via-htaccess/)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

Łukasz